# How to pass this two parameters in postman --proxy-header "Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --proxy abc.xyz.com:1234

Tags: api, authentication, curl, proxy, postman

How to pass this two parameters in postman 
--proxy-header "Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --proxy abc.xyz.com:1234

Where to specify this two parameter in postman ?

I have reviwed postman proxy settings - there we can give only hostname and port . not sure where to provide the username and password for the proxy authentication.

Comment: try this https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3566#issuecomment-400856387

Comment: Thanks for the link , its worked for me .

Answer (score 3):

Using latest native postman on windows (v6.2.3) and mac, pass proxy basic auth by doing the following.

1. Enter your proxy auth uname/pwd in the authorization section and
   click preview request which should copy the base64 version of the
   login to a header var.
2. Copy that base64 value into a new header key called
   "Proxy-Authorization"
3. Go back into authorization and either clear the values or change to 
   uname/pwd that your end point may require.
4. Ensure the proxy is set in the Postman settings minus the auth which
   doesn't stick or set it in the system proxy info

Comment: great @SolomonRaja !